# Python records connecting to Oracle

Tags: python-3.x, cx-oracle, python-records

I am using Kenneth Ritz's records library to connect to Oracle.

```
db = records.Database('oracle://scott/tiger@localhost:1521/orcl')
```

But it always throws this error

```
DatabaseError: (cx_Oracle.DatabaseError) 
ORA-12545: Connect failed because target host 
or object does not exist.
```

However, connecting via SQL Plus works just fine

```
sqlplus scott/tiger@localhost/orcl:1521

SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.1.0 Production on Sat Mar 11 17:29:19 2017

Copyright (c) 1982, 2013, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Last Successful login time: Sat Mar 11 2017 17:16:24 +05:30

Connected to:
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Advanced Analytics and Real Application Testing options

SQL>
```

Interesting Observation

```
db = cx_Oracle.connect('scott/tiger@localhost:1521/orcl') **<--Works**

db.version
'12.1.0.1.0'

db = records.Database('oracle+cx_oracle://scott/tiger@localhost:1521/orcl')
doesn't work
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`records` relies `sqlalchemy` to do the database heavy-lifting.
Please refer to the SQLAlchemy [documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/oracle.html#dialect-oracle-cx_oracle-connect):

So, the URI should be something like:
`oracle+cx_oracle://user:pass@localhost:1521/dbname`

Comment: Thanks Uku for the pointer.Tried this db = records.Database('oracle+cx_oracle://scott/tiger@localhost:1521/orcl') but still no joy

Comment: what is the meaning of `scott/tiger` part?

Comment: Sorry my bad this works scott is the username and password is tiger.db = records.Database('oracle+cx_oracle://scott:tiger@localhost:1‌​521/orcl')